# How can I tell that my matrix is nilpotent?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, nilpotence

I just computed a 15x15 matrix by hand :(

It is not upper triangular as I hoped it would be.  But my computations agree with what's offered in the student solution.

My question is:  the solution then says "this matrix is nilpotent, so all the eigenvalues are zero."

I get the part where the spectrum = {0} i.f.f. the operator is nilpotent, but how can I tell it actually is nilpotent, just by observing the matrix that I got?

EDIT: Here is my computation of the matrix:

The vector space is the space of polynomials in two variables x,y, of degree less than or equal to 4.

So, I let the basis for this space be the set $${ 1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4, y, y^2, y^3, y^4, xy, xy^2, x^2y, xy^3, x^2y^2, x^3y }$$

The operator is a Laplacian operator on polynomials:

f(x,y) --> f(x+1,y) + f(x-1,y) + f(x,y-1) + f(x,y+1) - 4f(x,y), for f(x,y) in V.

With the above (ordered) basis, I applied this Laplacian operator to each basis element.  I wrote each result as a linear combination of the ordered basis.  Now, taking the transpose of the coefficients, the matrix w.r.t. the ordered basis is:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
         0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
         0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0   & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
         0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 12& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
         0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
         0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
         0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0   & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
         0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 12   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
         0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
         0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
         0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 6 \\
         0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
         0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
         0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
         0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
         0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

And thanks to the commenters (below), I now see that my matrix is indeed nilpotent, since it is upper triangular, with zeros on the main diagonal; in my initial sketch of the matrix - I was way off. :-)

(I had thought that the 6's were below the diagonal.)

Thanks,

Comment: Oh goodness.. Is there any nice structure that your matrix has?

Comment: Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix and btw, things like this don't get solved just by looking by them, unless some rare cases

Comment: Could you show us your $15 \times 15$ matrix? Without seeing it or getting a better description of it, it is impossible to tell you why it is nilpotent.

Comment: Isn't the trace the sum of the eigenvalues, so you should be able to inspect your result and determine if its nilpotent, ie trace(A) = 0? (Wikipedia)https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29

Comment: I got it now - thanks, as usual, @CameronWilliams :-)

Comment: Got it - thanks so much @JimmyK4542 for suggesting me to be more explicit and write out the entire matrix; it's now obvious :-)

Comment: Hi @cockneywanker, no, that would be the *sum* of eigenvalues, but the trace would not tell you the *spectrum* of the operator.  (Unless, of course, it's already upper diagonal; then you can just read off the eigenvalues.) So, trace(A) = 0 does not imply the operator is nilpotent.  Take 4 and -4 as your eigenvalues, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Leafar - yes, great reminder from Wiki that a nilpotent matrix need not have a lot of zeroes  - or any zeroes - in it :-)

Comment: Hi @CameronWilliams, is the Jordan Normal form easily described for this particular matrix, without computation of higher powers of the matrix and its generalized eigenvectors?  (I posted this as a new question on MSE just now, too.)  Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is too large for a comment, but I thought it might help to shed some light on the underlying reason that the matrix should be expected to be upper-triangular, and indeed nilpotent (so that you would sooner suspect an error in formatting, or perhaps in the choice of basis order).

Your transformation (call it $L[f]$) can be broken down into $L[f] = L_x[f] + L_y[f]$, where

$$ L_x[f(x,y)] = f(x+1,y) + f(x-1,y) - 2f(x,y),$$
$$ L_y[f(x,y)] = f(x,y+1) + f(x,y-1) - 2f(x,y).$$

Now notice that $L_x$ has the effect of reducing the $x$-degree of any polynomial you put into it, without increasing the $y$-degree.  That's because the coefficients $(1,1,-2)$ sum to zero so the highest $x$-degree term of $f$ gets cancelled out in computing $L_x[f]$ (and nothing happens to the $y$-coefficients attached to that term).

[In fact we could say more: $L_x$ is a *second-difference operator* which acts much like a second derivative, so it actually lowers the $x$-degree by $2$.]

Similarly, $L_y$ has the effect of lowering the $y$-degree without raising the $x$-degree.  So together, $L_x + L_y$ has the net effect of consistently lowering the degree of $f$.  Morally, this is the real reason why the matrix is nilpotent: if you keep lowering the degree enough times, eventually any polynomial you start with will go to $0$, just as in repeated differentiation.

You might have noticed that while computing the effect of the Laplacian on each basis polynomial, the terms that come out always seem to be composed of basis polynomials occurring *earlier* in the list.  If you think about it, this is exactly what it means for your matrix to be (strictly) upper-triangular.

But for your particular choice of basis ordering, there was a bit of coincidence involved (several of the basis polynomials transform to $0$, so the ordering among those polynomials doesn't matter so much).  From the above discussion, the idea that each basis polynomial breaks down into terms to the left becomes *much* more obvious when you sort them by total degree, for instance:

$$1,x,y,x^2,xy,y^2,x^3,x^2y,xy^2,y^3,x^4,x^3y,x^2y^2,xy^3,y^4.$$

This also highlights the fact that questions like these can be sensitive to the basis order.  Choosing a different ordering (which is equivalent to swapping rows and then swapping the corresponding columns) can turn a non-triangular matrix into a triangular one.  For a random nilpotent matrix this strategy isn't likely to bear fruit [which is probably why it didn't show up in any earlier comments written before you added the critical details of the matrix origin].

Comment: Hi @ErickWong, thanks so much for this awesome write-up.  Can I ask you a follow-up question?  If I wanted to show that the operator is nilpotent, *without* computing higher powers of the matrix until I get the zero matrix, how could I do so with just the way L is defined?  I am tempted to say to myself "use linearity of L, and look at L(L(f(x,y)) = $L^2$(f(x,y)), and see whether it is clear that the degree of the image polynomial is lowered yet again.  But...L isn't *linear*, is it?  On a second thought, perhaps it is:  it is simply an addition of four polynomials, minus one polynomial ...

Comment: A slight edit to my first comment:  *without* even computing the action of the Laplacian on the 15 basis vectors ... and computing the matrix representation ... (which was a lot of computation ...)

Comment: Actually, I'll try to show that L((f(x,y)) + g(x,y)) = L(f) + L(g), and a*L(f) = L(af) now...perhaps it's easier than I think :-)

Comment: @LebronJames Yes, the action of $L$ is linear; if it weren't, you couldn't represent it as a matrix in the first place.  You might be thinking of the fact that the polynomials are not linear functions of $x$ and $y$, but that would be a red herring since the domain of $L$ Is not $x$ and $y$ but the vector space of polynomials.  You are exactly right that all you need to show is that $L(f+g) = L(f)+L(g)$ and $L(af) = aL(f)$.

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks so much @ErickWong!  :-)

Answer (score 5):

Your matrix is a strictly upper triangular matrix. Upper triangular matrices $n\times n$ are all nilpotent since their characteristic polynomials, $\det (A-XI_n)$, is equal to $(-1)^nX^n$. According to Cayley-Hamilton's Theorem, $(-1)^nA^n=0\Rightarrow A^n=0$.

Comment: This is such a simple and awesome reminder of how one can use the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, @Scientifica :-)  Thanks so much for sharing - have a great day!

Comment: @LebronJames It's a pleasure. When I had as an exercise to prove that strictly upper triangular matrices are nilpotent, I didn't study yet Vector Spaces, so I proved it by calculus (It was really complicated hhh).